# IBM Webpshere Full profile, Webpshere traditional profile and Websphere classic profile

Tags: websphere

It is more confusing for a non-Websphere expert to differentiate between different types of Websphere terminologies being used by IBM. I was trying to understand the difference between
1) Websphere Full profile
2) Base Websphere profile
3) Websphere Traditional Profile
4) Websphere Classic Profile.
5) WAS

I see that IBM uses above terminologies everywhere. However not sure what is the difference. Not sure why there are no naming standards set.
Are all above mean the same or they are all different?

Comment: I have a hard time finding proper off-topic category for this question. I'm still pretty sure it is off-topic as it is not related to programming.

Answer (score 10):

Short answer: They're all the same thing - references that imply the original version of WebSphere Application Server, rather than WebSphere Liberty, the newer, smaller-footprint server version that shipped with 8.5.  The official full name is "WebSphere Application Server traditional".

Long answer:

- "Full Profile" was the original term used to differentiate between the
  traditional server and the Liberty server (originally referred to as
  "Liberty Profile").  Ultimately the use of "profile" was confusing
  (it's a server, not a server configuration profile), and Liberty
  matured into a full-featured server, so "Full Profile" was phased out.
- "Base" generally refers to the single-server image of the traditional server - it differentiates not from Liberty, but from Network Deployment (ND).
- "Traditional" I covered above.
- "Classic" was briefly used as the term to differentiate between traditional and Liberty, but it ultimately was shelved in favor of "traditional".
- "WAS" is the acronym for the full product name, "WebSphere Application Server" - since "WebSphere" is a branding line beyond just the application server products, "WAS" is often used for slightly more specificity (although I'd note that the two server versions are "WAS traditional" and "WAS Liberty", so it's not specific between those).

Comment: Thanks Jarid. Any idea when was it officially declared as "WebSphere Application Server traditional". Just would like to know the sequence of their arrival.

Comment: I can't recall specifically, but to the best of my recollection, the "traditional" term was set when WAS traditional 9.0 was announced... that shipped last summer, so it's probably been somewhere around two years, total, that the term has been officially in use.  "Full Profile" and "Classic" came before "traditional", in that order, and I don't think "Classic" was ever used officially in a product release, although as your question shows, the term obviously made it out into the wild.

Comment: Thanks Jarid for the clarification